# how to access secrets from jenkins in .scala file?

Tags: scala, jenkins, configuration, environment-variables

I have a Secret text binding Variable SECRET_TKN in jenkins job configuration. I want to access this var in .scala file . How do I access this var generically in my code?

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
val token =sys.env("${SECRET_TKN}")
println ("value = " +token)
```

Console output shows value as `SOME(***)` thus causing the api calls to fail as I believe the keyword SOME is coming along with the actual fetched value.

Also, tried sys.env("${?STG_SERVICE_TKN}") but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sys.env`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/sys/index.html#env:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]) is keyed by variable name, so this should work:

```
val token = sys.env("SECRET_TKN")
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes, it is working now.  I think using like "${SECRET_TKN}" was a mistake that caused an issue .

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking on [checkmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).

Answer (score 1):

For your case, it would work if the `SECRET_TKN` is a variable being populated, it would work fine:

```
val SECRET_TKN =  "SECRET_TKN"
val token =sys.env(s"${SECRET_TKN}")
```

It's better practice to use `sys.env.get("mySecret")` which will give you an `Option[String]` rather than throw an error if that variable is missing.

Comment: This SECRET_TKN is embedded in jenkins so its being populated. However using like this did not work ```sys.env("${SECRET_TKN}") ``` . But instead using just `sys.env("SECRET_TKN") works fine.

Comment: @OBarros I think you meant `val token = sys.env(s"${SECRET_TKN}")` (note `s` before string); also in OP's case `SECRET_TKN` val should be `"SECRET_TKN"`, like `val SECRET_TKN =  "SECRET_TKN"`.